# Xamarin forms. get winPhone's App Prop's in PCL

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get the prop's from my WinPhone solutions in my xamarin froms project so that i can use them in my PCL.

So that in my App/PCL can do something like

App.WinPhone.Prop = 2;
Or
Var temp = App.WinPhone.Prop

thank for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a new class in your WP Native project. e.g.

```
[assembly: Dependency (typeof(MyProperties))]
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class MyProperties: IMyProperties
    {

         public string TheProperty { get { return "something"; } }

    }
}
```

Create the appropriate interface in your PCL.

Then in your PCL do

```
 DependencyService.Get<IMyProperties>().TheProperty
```

This webpage has more information: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Plugins/tree/master/Settings) from James Montemagno will help you.